# Email with Attachment with Umlaut in sender displayname (or email)

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, utf-8, email-attachments

I'm trying to send an email with an attachment via python, but I get an error from the sending server that the email isn't RFC 5321/5322 compliant when the displayname (or the email) contain a german umlaut 'äöü'. With none of them the mail sending works fine.
I checked several other questions, but their issues weren't in the sender or weren't sending an attachment so those solutions didn't work for my case.

Minimal working example (well not working, but working if you remove the 'ö' from 'displayname'; login/passwort missing and email addresses changed for obvious reasons), I'm using python 3.11 on windows:

```
import smtplib
import ssl
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

message = MIMEMultipart()
message.set_charset('utf-8')
subject = 'Support-Nr. 1'
message["Subject"] = subject
body = 'testmail 123 äöüß'
message.attach(MIMEText(body, "plain"))
filename = 'VCARD_A & B.vcf'
with open(filename, "rb") as attachment:
    part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(attachment.read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header(
    "Content-Disposition",
    f"attachment; filename= {filename}",
)
message.attach(part)
sender_email = 'email1@example.com'
receiver_email = 'email2@example.com'
displayname = 'Höhne'
message["From"] = displayname + '<' + sender_email + '>'
message["To"] = receiver_email
smtplogin = #loginname
smtppassword = #passwort
smtpserver = 'smtp.ionos.de'
smtpport = 465
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtpserver, smtpport, context=context) as server:
    server.login(smtplogin, smtppassword)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message.as_string())
```

Comment: Maybe `message["From"] = quopri.encodestring( displayname.encode('utf-8')) + '<' + sender_email + '>'`? Of course, `import quopri` required…

Comment: @JosefZ no, that either has an error of concating a string and bytes or (if i encode the whole string) theres another "byte has no method encode" error on server.sendmail, so that tries to encode it but not in utf-8? idk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else looking for a solution I found an example on [the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) which works.

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'Support-Nr. 1'
sender_email = 'email1@example.com'
receiver_email = 'email2@example.com'
displayname = 'Höhne'
msg['From'] = displayname + '<' + sender_email + '>'
msg['To'] = receiver_email
msg.preamble = 'You will not see this in a MIME-aware mail reader.\n'
with open('VCARD_A & B.vcf', 'rb') as fp:
    img_data = fp.read()
    file_name = fp.name
msg.add_attachment(img_data, maintype='application', subtype='octet-stream', filename=file_name)
body = 'test123 äöüß'
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, "plain"))
smtplogin = #loginname
smtppassword = #password
smtpserver = 'smtp.ionos.de'
smtpport = 465
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtpserver, smtpport, context=context) as s:
    s.login(smtplogin, smtppassword)
    s.send_message(msg)
```